# Storing relational data in a Lucene.NET index

Tags: c#, lucene.net, search

I'm currently trying to implement a Lucene.NET based search on a large database and I've hit a snag trying to do a search on what is essentially relational data.

At a high level the data I'm trying to search is grouped, each item belongs to 1 to 3 groups. I then need to be able to do a search for all items that are in a combination of groups (EG: Each item belongs to both group A and group B).

Each of these groupings have ID's and Descriptions existing from the data I'm searching, but the descriptions may be sub-strings of one another (EG: One group named "Stuff" and the other "Other stuff"), and I don't want to match the categories that have a sub-string of the one I'm looking for.

I've been considering pulling the data back without this filtering and then filtering the ID's, but I was intending to paginate the data returned from Lucene for performance reasons. I've also considered putting the ID's in space-separated and doing a text-search on the field, but that seems like a total hack...

Does anyone have any idea how to best handle this kind of search in Lucene.NET? (Just to clarify before someone says I'm using the wrong tool, this is only a subset of a larger set of filters which includes full-text searching. If you still think I'm using the wrong tool though I'd love to hear what the right one is)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had my share of problems with storing relational data i Lucene but the one you have should be easy to fix.

I guess you tokenize the group fields and that makes it possible to search for substrings in the field value. Just add the field untokenized and it should work like expected.

Please check the following small piece of code:

```
internal class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var directory = new RAMDirectory();
        var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new StandardAnalyzer());
        AddDocument(writer, "group", "stuff", Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED);
        AddDocument(writer, "group", "other stuff", Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED);
        writer.Close(true);

        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory);
        Hits hits = searcher.Search(new TermQuery(new Term("group", "stuff")));

        for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length(); i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(hits.Doc(i).GetField("group").StringValue());
        }
    }

    private static void AddDocument(IndexWriter writer, string name, string value, Field.Index index) {
        var document = new Document();
        document.Add(new Field(name, value, Field.Store.YES, index));
        writer.AddDocument(document);
    }
}
```

The sample adds two documents to the index which are untokenized, does a search for stuff and gets one hit. If you changed the code to add them tokenized then you will have two hits as you see now.

The issue with using Lucene for relational data is that it might be expected that wildcard and range searches always will work. That is not really the case if the index is big due to way Lucene resolves those queries.

Another sample to illustrate the behavior:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var directory = new RAMDirectory();
        var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new StandardAnalyzer());

        var documentA = new Document();
        documentA.Add(new Field("name", "A", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
        documentA.Add(new Field("group", "stuff", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
        documentA.Add(new Field("group", "other stuff", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
        writer.AddDocument(documentA);
        var documentB = new Document();
        documentB.Add(new Field("name", "B", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
        documentB.Add(new Field("group", "stuff", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
        writer.AddDocument(documentB);
        var documentC = new Document();
        documentC.Add(new Field("name", "C", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
        documentC.Add(new Field("group", "other stuff", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
        writer.AddDocument(documentC);

        writer.Close(true);

        var query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("group", "stuff"));
        SearchAndDisplay("First sample", directory, query1);

        var query2 = new TermQuery(new Term("group", "other stuff"));
        SearchAndDisplay("Second sample", directory, query2);

        var query3 = new BooleanQuery();
        query3.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("group", "stuff")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        query3.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("group", "other stuff")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        SearchAndDisplay("Third sample", directory, query3);
    }

    private static void SearchAndDisplay(string title, Directory directory, Query query3) {
        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory);
        Hits hits = searcher.Search(query3);
        Console.WriteLine(title);
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length(); i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(hits.Doc(i).GetField("name").StringValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi HakonB, thanks for the reply. I have used untokenized for a few other lookups but the problem is one item can be in both "Stuff" and "Other Stuff" and it needs to be found when searching for either or both.

EG:
A in stuff and other stuff
B in just stuff
C in just other stuff

Search for stuff {A,B}
Search for other stuff {A,C}
Search for stuff and other stuff {A}

Comment: I've added another sample that illustrates how to get the correct results - that is if I understand you now :-)

Comment: Ah, thanks! That seems like exactly what I was after. It never occurred to me that I could actually add 2 fields of the same name to 1 document. Still thinking too much like a typical relational database I guess =)