# is it possible in java-lucene to map multifield values?

Tags: search, lucene, indexing

i have a single document in lucene index with multiple fields and some of the fields are multivalued for example

`Document{ field1: field2: field3: .... field9:}`

and fields are like

```
field1:some string value
field2:some int value
.
.
.
field8:(string values that are space separated and each is a token )//uid for some items
field9:(value or items whose uid is in field8 and both field8 and field9 are one to one map)
```

With this i am able to search and index a multivalued field in a flat document structure now i have an other field say `field10`: in which i have multiple values against a single uid in `field8` then how can i index and search this new field in this structure using lucene

i want to index and then map the `field10` values against `field8`, for example

```
field8: {     uid1    | uid2     | uid3} 
field10:{id1,id2,id3  | id1,id7  | id1 }
```

help required
regards

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you're asking. Suppose you have a document like:

```
field8:  {    1    |    2    |    3    }
field10: { foo,bar | baz,foo | bar,baz }
```

You want to have the query `+field8:1 +field10:foo` return this document, but `+field8:3 +field10:foo` shouldn't return the document.

This is a relational data model, and it's not something Lucene tries to be good at. Your best bet is to use a relational database.

If you want to stick with Lucene, you should split each one of these fields into its own document. So one doc would be `field8:1, field10: foo,bar` etc. Alternatively you could have your own tokenizer which used payloads or term positions to handle this. I don't know that it would be particularly easy or fast.

There are many questions on this site regarding your problem, e.g. [Storing relational data in a Lucene.NET index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760576/storing-relational-data-in-a-lucene-net-index)